# Не работает jQuery .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend

Не работает код. Слышал, что в `css` нельзя анимировать `text-align`, я подумал, через `js` можно. Я менял свойство `color`, но тоже не работает. Т.е. уже дело не в `text-align`. В чем может быть проблема?

html:

```
<div class="login">
  <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>login</p>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.login').mouseover(function() { 
        $(".login p").animate({ text-align: "right" }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: text-align это css стиль, а не анимирующее свойство.

Answer (score 2):

Для тех, кто из 2020 года или позже:

$(".login p").animate({ textAlign: "right" }, 1000);

В javascript тире считается как минус, запомните это как правило!
Вместо тире мы первую букву следующего слова возносим в верхний регистр.
Поэтому будет textAlign

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказал ранее [Jean-Claude](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11368/jean-claude), text-align — это не анимирующее свойство.

Анимировать на CSS всё же можно:

```
.login p {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  right: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
}
.login p:hover {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/yt9eydju/